# Accessing values that are appended to a list in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, immutability

I want to generate different permutations of the weight list that I have and add all the permutations to an outer list. This code generates the permutations correctly but even if i add it to the outer list, it is empty when I print it in the end.

I thought this was  call by reference since lists are mutable, so any change made to the list in the function will be reflected outside the scope of the function also.

How can I correct this code, so that the outer list will contain all the permutations with each permutation as a list, outside the function?

```
weight = [100,120,140]
outer_list = []
def func(outer_list,inner_list,weight,i,max_val):
    if len(inner_list) == max_val:
        print inner_list
        outer_list.append(inner_list)
        return
    inner_list.append(weight[i])
    func(outer_list,inner_list,weight,i,max_val)
    del inner_list[-1]
    for j in range(i+1,len(weight)):
        inner_list.append(weight[j])
        func(outer_list,inner_list,weight,i,max_val)
        del inner_list[-1]


inner_list = []
func(outer_list,inner_list,weight,0,2)
print outer_list
```

Current output:

```
[100, 100]
[100, 120]
[100, 140]
[120, 100]
[120, 120]
[120, 140]
[140, 100]
[140, 120]
[140, 140]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the list is modified.  One thing you seem to have missed: you appended `inner_list` to `outer_list`, but you didn't copy it first.  It is still mutable, and all of the `inner_list`s that you appended are the same object.  Just use a copy instead:

```
        outer_list.append(inner_list[:])
```

The `[:]` is a slice.  Since we left out the start, it defaults to the beginning.  Since we left out the stop, it defaults to the end.  Therefore, we made a slice of the entire list which results in a shallow copy.

A shallow copy is all that is needed in this case, but note that if `inner_list` contained mutable objects which were also subject to change, you would need a deep copy.  To get a deep copy, you can use the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Good catch! I'll admit, I was stumped on this one. Ah the pitfalls of state and mutable data...

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out in your post that `[:]` only creates a *shallow* copy. While that will work fine for this specific question, I think that information should be included for other people who stumble upon this in the future and have nested data structures.

Comment: @PierceDarragh: That is certainly worth pointing out, and it is now in the post.

Comment: @zondo much appreciated!